# How to Show two tablix on each page of report viewer in C#

Tags: c#, reporting-services, report, ssrs-tablix

I Have created a report in report viewer and I want to show two tablix on one page of report viewer.

For example if both tables have 10 rows to show then i want to show 5 rows of first table and 5 rows of second table on 1 page and rest of the rows show on next page like next 5 rows from first table and next 5 rows from second table.

How can I got this?
Please Help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some criteria to group by. For example, add pageNumber column to each of two datasets and then add group by this column to each table and set to page break by this value.